# Ensuring folder name doesn't show up in the domain name

Tags: model-view-controller, hosting, dns

our hosting account is set up with the domain www.nashman.ca, and our application is at www.nashman.ca/hub. We have another domain that forwards to www.nashman.ca/hub and that's hub.mhn.co. The problem i'm having with this is that the forwarded domain adds on the /hub whenever you navigate to another page from hub.mhn.co, so the domain shows as hub.mhn.co/hub/admin when you're in the admin area, for example. I need the domain to stay consistent, and never show that folder name, because its breaking some of the javascript I use. What is the best way to set this up?

**edit**

I've been doing some reading about URL Rewriting, and looking into it - my hosting provider supports the IIS7 URL Rewrite module. All the tutorials I've found so far detail how to set up rules using the IIS config tools, but I don't have access to them. Is there a way to do it by editing my web.config in my apps root directory? And will this solve my issue?

Comment: Are you sure you posted this in the right place? This sounds like a question for whomever set up you the site. Otherwise, just use relative links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the default page for hub.mhn.co using a redirect to www.nashman.ca? If so, what is happening is that the forwarding software basically returns a new URI that the browser requests, and the new URI will replace the old one in the browser window and thus in all future requests. You're probably redirecting to ~/hub/ (the hub subdirectory of the site root) which will result in the browser requesting a new URI that keeps the domain name but tacks on the subdirectory.

If you have direct control over the DNS and your webservers, you can use the DNS configuration to direct a request for the hub.mhn.co domain directly to the /hub subdirectory of your webserver. That way, the browser never knows that hub.mhn.co is actually www.nashman.ca/hub/. You might have to direct to an alternate port on the webserver and map that port to the subdirectory, depending on your DNS software (IIRC, most can deal with ipaddress/subdir routes, but some can only handle routing to ipaddress:port).

If your IT department does not have direct control/ownership over your DNS routing, or your exact hosting environment, you are more or less at the mercy of your hosting provider. They may be able to set up their environment to do the same thing, or not; all you can do is ask.

EDIT: Basically you have two options left if you're hosting remotely and can't use their DNS to reroute silently.

First option: clone (copy all files from) the web layer of nashman.ca/hub as hub.mhn.co under a different root space in your hosting environment (try to keep any hooks to service-layer code over at nashman so you don't have to copy the whole vertical slice). If you must also keep the UI under the /hub/ subdirectory, you're repeating code, but you may be able to mitigate this with deploy scripts that will allow you to deploy one local copy of your codebase to various locations. This may also cost more as your hosting environment is now hosting two non-trivial sites.

Second option: host the site and/or resolve the calls on your own hardware. As long as you have a public, static IP address through your ISP, you can provide a DNS server that will be the "authoritative" server for nashman.ca and hub.mhn.co domains. Your ISP or a third party domain name registry can provide a "pass-down" route to get requests from the TLD servers down to you. Then, you can route requests to whatever IP address, port and/or subfolder you like; that can be a remote webhosting provider (as long as they don't mind JUST hosting your site) or your own webservers. This will require the hardware, and a static IP from your ISP. If you lose power to this server, your site will be unreachable until power's restored. If the IP address of your DNS server changes, your site will be unaccessible by DNS until the server that routes requests to you updates its routing table with the new IP (which can be up to 24 hours).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, it does seem like my site is redirecting. All of my links are ~/Controller/Action or ~/Area/Controller/Action as built by Url.Content() We will contact the hosting provider.

Comment: Yeah they were pretty useless in helping us. We can't do the ipaddress:port idea because they wont forward the port to the folder due to some policy about touching our files. I'm still looking for a solution.

Comment: We're going to go with our own DNS server sometime down the road(our isp sucks at the moment), but for now we're just working around the issue. Thanks for your assistance.